# How to add default code to every cpp file that I open in vim?

Tags: c++, windows, vim

I've recently got started with competitive programming. I see a lot of competitors use vim in the competition.
I want to add default code to every CPP file that I might open in vim so that I don't have to type the following routine code and a few Macros as well every time. please help me. thanks in advance.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
             return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create a template file and copy it.

Comment: Never do this `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.  Never do this `using namespace std;`.  In C++, `return 0;` is implicit for `main`.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be to create the template file and read it using the `:r` command in vim. The next step would be using an autocommand on *.cpp files, whenever you create a new File. see `:h autocmd-groups`